# How to return array element in java [Ljava.lang.String;@139bb134

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return-value

I am trying to return an array but its throwing garbage values. Here is my code:

```
int currentPage = 1;
String[] page = {page1, page2, page3};
    page = new String[currentPage];
return page;
```

**Updated**

```
    public static String[] pagingIndex(int currentPage, int lastPage, String url) {
    
    String pageHeader = "<li class=\"page-item\"><a class=\"page-link\" href=\""+url;
    String currentPageHeader = "<li class=\"page-item active\" aria-current=\"page\"><a class=\"page-link\">";
    String pageFooter = "</a></li>";
    
    String page1 = 
            currentPageHeader + (currentPage) + pageFooter +
            pageHeader + (currentPage + 1) +"\">" + (currentPage + 1) + pageFooter +
            pageHeader + (currentPage + 2) +"\">" + (currentPage + 2) + pageFooter;
    
    String page2 = 
            pageHeader + (currentPage - 1) +"\">" + (currentPage - 1) + pageFooter +
            currentPageHeader + (currentPage) + pageFooter +
            pageHeader + (currentPage + 1) +"\">" + (currentPage + 1) + pageFooter;
    
    String page3 = 
            pageHeader + (currentPage - 2) +"\">" + (currentPage - 2) + pageFooter +
            pageHeader + (currentPage - 1) +"\">" + (currentPage - 1) + pageFooter +
            currentPageHeader + (currentPage) + pageFooter;
    
    String[] page = {page1, page2, page3};
return page[currentPage];
}
```

Here is my complete code. I am trying to show one page whereas having 3 total pages. Now printing as following

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    String url = "http://localhost:8080";
    System.out.println(Paging.pagingIndex(1, 9, url)); 
    }
```

Now its output is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
> problem:      Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]
>
> at parvaz.commons.paging.Paging.pagingIndex(Paging.java:193)    at
> parvaz.Testing.main(Testing.java:9)

Comment: Who is throwing what again? Please show how you use the return value. Most probably you're trying to print the array in the wrong way.

Comment: Use java.util.Arrays.toString to show readable array values. And show a [mcve], what’s posted doesn’t look like it’s valid.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a new string array of size 1.
By saying `page = new String[currentPage]` you're overwriting page to be a new array of size 1.
I assume you instead wanted to do `return page[currentPage];` to return a single page.

Edit: You also have to adjust the return type of in your method signature to String instead of String[].

Comment: `  String[] page = {page1, page2, page3};
    return page[currentPage];` eclipse throw error by saying `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]`

Comment: @JoshiK it's hard to help you if you don't show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question and don't explain what the goal of your code actually is. But the error you're getting seems to depend on the fact that your method returns an array, while VocalTrance answer will make it return a string. So what are you trying to do, really?

Comment: You have to change your methods signature to return String instead of String[].
Edit: Still assuming, that your method wants to return a single page.

Comment: @VocalTrance you should incorporate that into your answer. It's rather essential for it to work.

Comment: @VocalTrance when I apply your advice then its throwing error. Please check I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Method signature of `pagingIndex` to `String`. So you change it to:

```
public static String pagingIndex(int currentPage, int lastPage, String url) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return page[currentPage];
}
```